# Getting an error while creating SQL function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a SQL function (MS-SQL) to be used in a sproc to create random strings of a random length.  When I write the entire function out, the Create Function line gets the red line of doom, claiming that "Incorrect syntax:  Create Function must be the only statement in the batch."

Code is as follows:

```
Create Function dbo.randomtesttext (@length int)
returns varchar(999)
as
Begin
    declare @pool varchar
    set @pool = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
    declare @return varchar(999)
    declare @position int = 0
    while (@position < @length)
    begin
        set @return = @return + (select substring(@pool, convert(int, rand()*36), 1))
        set @position = @position + 1
    end
    return @return
end
```

Any thoughts?  I'm sure the answer is a simple one that I'm just not experienced enough to see.

Comment: That error is caused by the other code you have around this function. Surround it with `go`s. However, you can't use `rand` in a function.

Comment: aside, you are not incrementing `@position` so this will get you into an infinite loop, unless `@length` is 0.

Comment: I saw that as soon as I posted the code, and knew I'd get assassinated on it.  I do have an increment in place, I just forgot to type it out.  I am instead using While loops to assemble random strings instead of a function.  Less processant, but these are one-offs for testing data, so the efficiency isn't a big concern.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `RAND` build-in function in your user defined function. Anyway, you can use the following workaround putting `RAND` in a view:

```
CREATE VIEW rndView
AS
SELECT RAND() rndResult
GO
```

and then call it in your function like this:

```
Create Function dbo.randomtesttext (@length int)
returns varchar(999)
as
Begin
    declare @pool varchar
    set @pool = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
    declare @return varchar(999)
    declare @position int = 0
    while (@position < @length)
    begin
        set @return = @return + (select substring(@pool, convert(int, rndResult*36), 1) FROM rndView)
    end
    return @return
end
```

Comment: I did this as described.  The view generates, and spits out RAND's, but when I try to call rndResult in the function, the SSMS spits back a 'bad column' error.

Comment: Or if I try to use it as database.schema.table.column, I get a multi-part identifier cannot be bound error.

Comment: @Technohydra How you are calling the function: `SELECT dbo.randomtesttext (5)` ?

Comment: currently I have it stuck in a variable assign, as in select @orgid = dbo.ranomint(9)

Comment: Could you should the final code of your `dbo.ranomint` function?

Answer (score 0):

```
Create View rndView
as 
SELECT RAND() rndValue
GO

Declare @length int

Create Function dbo.randomint (@length int)
returns Varchar(50)
AS 
BEGIN
declare @positin int = 0
declare @numPool varchar = '1234567890'
declare @returnNum varchar = ''
while @position <= @Length
Begin
set @returnNum = @returnNum + (select Substring(@numPool, convert(int, rndValue*10),1))
set @position = @position + 1
end
return @returnNum
end
```

Comment: @gotqn This is the code I have ATM.  The hitch is that it keeps telling me that rndValue is an invalid column, or if I try to use the full name, that the multipart ID cannot be bound.

Comment: First of all, you should delete this answer and edit your question in order to add the code above in it. Then, there are a lot of errors in the code itself - firs there is typo in `declare @positin int = 0` and you have missed to include `from rndView` -it should be `set @returnNum = @returnNum + (select Substring(@numPool, convert(int, rndValue*10),1) from rndView) `